# How does equality work for numeric types?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I see that Haskell allows different numeric types to be compared:

```
*Main> :t 3
3 :: Num t => t
*Main> :t 3.0
3.0 :: Fractional t => t
*Main> 3 == 3.0
True
```

Where is the source code for the `Eq` instance for numeric types? If I create a new type, such as ComplexNumber, can I extend `==` to work for it? (I might want complex numbers with no imaginary parts to be potentially equal to real numbers.)

Comment: This is just an example of (extended?) defaulting rules in GHCi.

Comment: A perhaps confusing point here: although `3` and `3.0` have different polymorphic types, in the expression `3 == 3.0`, they are both given the same monomorphic type before the equality is computed. The type of `(==)` says it must accept two arguments with the same type: `Eq a => a -> a -> Bool`. I suspect misunderstanding this subtlety is what lead to the question.

Comment: "allows different numeric types to be compared". Try this: `length "abc" == 3.0`. Does it work?

Comment: @n.m. It does work in GHCi.

Comment: What version of GHCi?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

“Haskell allows different numeric types to be compared” no it doesn't. What Haskell actually allows is different types to be defined by the same *literals*. In particular, you can do

```
Prelude> let a = 3.7 :: Double
Prelude> let b = 1   :: Double
Prelude> a + b
4.7
```

OTOH, if I declared these explicitly with conflicting types, the addition would fail:

```
Prelude> let a = 3.7 :: Double
Prelude> let b = 1   :: Int
Prelude> a + b

<interactive>:31:5:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Double’ with actual type ‘Int’
    In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘b’
    In the expression: a + b
```

Now, `Double` is not the most general possible type for either `a` or `b`. In fact all number literals are polymorphic, but before any operation (like equality comparison) happens, such a polymorphic type needs to be pinned down to a concrete monomorphic one. Like,

```
Prelude> (3.0 :: Double) == (3 :: Double)
True
```

Because `==`, contrary to your premise, actually requires both sides to have the same type, you can omit the signature on either side without changing anything:

```
Prelude> 3.0 == (3 :: Double)
True
```

In fact, even without any type annotation, GHCi will still treat both sides as `Double`. This is because of [type defaulting](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#type-defaulting-in-ghci) – in this particular case, `Fractional` is the strongest constraint on the shared number type, and for `Fractional`, the default type is `Double`. OTOH, if both sides had been integral literals, then GHCi would have chosen `Integer`. This can sometimes make a difference, for instance

```
Prelude> 10000000000000000 == 10000000000000001
False
```

but

```
Prelude> 10000000000000000 ==(10000000000000001 :: Double)
True
```

because in the latter case, the final 1 is lost in the floating-point error.

Comment: Thank you. So I wouldn't be able to test equality to elements of a new type that I created?

Comment: Not from preexisting types, no.  And not even to other types you also created.  You can only compare type `a` to type `a`.

Comment: @espertus: you _can_ easily compare two values that are _both_ of a new type you've created yourself. Just write an [`Eq`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Eq) instance for that type.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing magical going on here. `3` can be of either a real number or an integer, but its type gets unified with a real number when compared to `3.0`.

Note the type class:

```
class Eq a where
  eq :: a -> a -> Bool
```

So `eq` really does only compare things of same type. And your example `3 == 3.0` gets its types unified and becomes `3.0 == 3.0` internally.

I'm unsure of any type tricks to make it unify with a user defined complex number type. My gut tells me it can not be done.

Comment: Nope. It can be done. Check this out: https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-790004.3.4 Now, if this defaulting mechanism was more general I would be happier...